# Can I create a data set using WITH before doing an INSERT in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to insert data from a spreadsheet into a MySQL table.  I wan't to verify the data combination doesn't already exists so I create the "stuff" dataset which contains the data from Excel.

MySQL doesn't seem to like that I'm using a WITH table (sorry don't know what these are called) before doing the insert.  Is it possible?

```
with stuff as(
select  '1005-BASE-BLACK' as external_sku, 'PMD WEBSITE' as retailer, '1005-Base-Black' as sku, 'ACCESSORIES' as cat, 'Charging Stand' as sub_cat
)

insert into retail_to_internal_sku(retailer, retail_sku, internal_sku, date_added)

select s.retailer, s.external_sku, s.sku, curdate() 
from stuff s
where not exists (select * from retail_to_internal_sku r 
                    where r.internal_sku = s.sku 
                    and r.retail_sku = s.external_sku
                    and r.retailer= s.retailer);
```

Comment: `WITH` goes before `SELECT`, not before `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you! the "insert into from cte" titled question didn't come up in my search, not really a helpful title.

Comment: If you know that `WITH` is used to start a CTE, it's a useful title.